# How to show all the data in one ListBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

I am new with WPF and I am struggling a little bit, trying to display all data in a list I can see the objects there in the view(two lines) but nothing is displayed like Name ??  any recommendation ?? Thank you

xaml :

```
<ListBox x:Name="nadjib">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

cs :

```
public ExecuteSpecificJobView()
        {
                InitializeComponent();
                List<string> ext = new List<string>();
                ext.Add(".txt");

                //itemsControl. = new List<string>(){ "ok","yes" };

               ObservableCollection<ViewModels.CreateJobViewModel.Model.TaskJsonAttribute> jobs = new ObservableCollection<ViewModels.CreateJobViewModel.Model.TaskJsonAttribute>();

               jobs.Add(new ViewModels.CreateJobViewModel.Model.TaskJsonAttribute { name = "aliii", source = "ok", target = "yess", type = "complete", extension = ext });
               jobs.Add(new ViewModels.CreateJobViewModel.Model.TaskJsonAttribute { name = "aliii", source = "ok", target = "yess", type = "complete", extension = ext });


               nadjib.ItemsSource = jobs;
        }



      public class TaskJsonAttribute
        {
            public string name;
            public string source;
            public string target;
            public string type;
            public List<string> extension;

            public string Name
            {
                get { return name; }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your objects have property "name" while you are trying to bind to "Name" (letter case). See the Output-window for error messages when running the program.

Comment: Well , my object has another property Name which returns "name"

Comment: Can you show how the type TaskJsonAttribute looks like?

Comment: Sure,TaskJsonAttribute  class added!

Comment: Maybe i misunderstood your problem. The two lines in the Listbox is visible showing the objects names. What do you mean with "displayed like Name"? Is it a header you expect to see?

Comment: I am trying to display at least the name attribute of the class TaskJsonAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little project that is similar to yours. This is showing the two names in the Listbox. See how this differ from yours.

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp9.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp9"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="nadjib">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp9
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ObservableCollection<TaskJsonAttribute> jobs = new ObservableCollection<TaskJsonAttribute>();

            jobs.Add(new TaskJsonAttribute() { name = "aliii-1" });
            jobs.Add(new TaskJsonAttribute() { name = "aliii-2" });

            nadjib.ItemsSource = jobs;

        }
    }

    public class TaskJsonAttribute
    {
        public string name;
        public string source;
        public string target;
        public string type;
        public List<string> extension;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
        }
    }
}
```